# Understanding a React Polymorphic Component: Generic Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, jsx, typescript-generics

I am building a React  component that accepts the following props:

- as: a tag e.g as = 'h3'
- className
- children

Here are my types:

```
type TextOwnProps<E extends React.ElementType> = {
    className: string
    children: React.ReactNode
    as?: E
}

// we now have all the types of the element except for the types that we have specified ourselves 
export type TextProps<E extends React.ElementType> = TextOwnProps<E> & Omit<React.ComponentProps<E>, keyof TextOwnProps<E>>
// we are removing our own types since they are props???
```

Here is the React component

```
// not useful unless you are building a component library or design system 
import React from 'react'

import { TextProps } from './text-types'

// h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,label, p,
// e.g <Text className = '' as = 'p'>{children} </p>
export function Text<E extends React.ElementType = 'div'>({ as, className, children }: TextProps<E>) {
    const TagName = as || 'div'

    return (
        <TagName className={className}>{children}</TagName>
    )
}

Text.displayName = '@Text'
```

My question is: Why pull out TextOwnProps with Omit. I mean:

```
export type TextProps<E extends React.ElementType> = TextOwnProps<E> & Omit<React.ComponentProps<E>, keyof TextOwnProps<E>>
```

In the end, TextProps equals our own props(TextOwnProps) and React.ComponentProps that again exludes our own props(TextOwnProps).

Why not just have:

```
export type TextProps<E extends React.ElementType> = TextOwnProps<E> & React.ComponentProps<E>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to avoid both types defining the same property in different ways, since the result can end up defining the property with the type `never` ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBDAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAXwG4AoUSKAIQWXSgIFcBbAIwh3KvGgDCDOADI6lADYRgUAMYYhiVBgAsAJl4B6TVF179APUBIRCaNQAKvygByVp27WoeTMwD2MlJkx4iBFBykoYFcgq1sIADcHIA)):

```
type A = {a: string};
type B = {a: number};
type C = A & B;
let c: C = {a: 42};
//          ^−−−− Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

So you omit any properties you're defining yourself in `TextOwnProps<E>` from `React.ComponentProps<E>` before doing the intersection.

Interestingly, doing that prevents invalid properties from being used on your `Text` component. The version **with** `Omit` correctly won't allow this:

```
// The `Omit` version correctly reports this error
const aDiv1 = <Text as="div" type="text" className="x">div</Text>;
//                           ^−−− Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextOwnProps<"div"> & Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, keyof TextOwnProps<...>>'.(2322)
```

If you just use `TextOwnProps<E> & React.ComponentProps<E>` instead, it allows `type` there even though `E` is `"div"` (not `"input"` or `"button"`), which is wrong. (I haven't figured out *why* yet, but in any case, you want to avoid overlapping property definitions, so doing the `Omit` makes sense.)

Full example showing that ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DZGnbLNZbA4NNm-GhAsFQtmMi4Hb6EQBKEw54VcNyMFBeAv0Iw2OAAHx7Sc6ZEofiIMGGUDFQgYbY7uZs9kcSAMxis847GV0K9LISkGSEOWn7cXDPIGXIDsUHQE8xQ1FnRnwAAEHUOVWrzsHQw1NbravqjWIJpRm6SiqJawLWp2A5dGmGZJAIRYWKu+aLoh5glkEO5NKeVavHCv6coaLr1nB6ENC2h73nA3Z9tBr4jkgY4TnAU4zouc4oRoy7IQuGgblumGhHuB5sRoJ5ng6BH-peFQ3ne7EPs+EivkyBTQMScjdvcqySNI5BNi2KBcAAklwYDDDAACMiZThI1ECAY+CeOZMDdFsjmSKw3Q8R2jnMCmzkWfuDonkyIhQDgUD2V8dAYEgekGfAKAACKdNZRi2aw9mOcmTx0B5ykcbxS74P5ujXMFEihfkalQBp0XaXFCXkUlJlmRZBo2ZJeoNJ1NiOYFrl5SVnlDT5i5+QF7UwJVrBSb11VwCICAIGwCBwHYbAMHAyUiAwIhYvtyUsYASERnedF2XVd103SdcAcDg3j6S11GpZUnUZd1f69dl7SDsNBVeUVvmlSmFUHhI82GgyQA)):

```
import React from "react";

type TextOwnProps<E extends React.ElementType> = {
    className: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    as?: E;
};

// With this version, the "div" trying to use `type` complains because `type` isn't valid for divs
export type TextProps<E extends React.ElementType> =
    TextOwnProps<E> & Omit<React.ComponentProps<E>, keyof TextOwnProps<E>>;
// With this version, it doesn't complain even though it should
export type TextPropsVersion2<E extends React.ElementType> =
    TextOwnProps<E> & React.ComponentProps<E>;

export function Text<E extends React.ElementType = "div">({
    as,
    className,
    children,
}: TextProps<E>) {
    const TagName = as || "div";

    return <TagName className={className}>{children}</TagName>;
}
Text.displayName = "@Text";

export function TextVersion2<E extends React.ElementType = "div">({
    as,
    className,
    children,
}: TextPropsVersion2<E>) {
    const TagName = as || "div";

    return <TagName className={className}>{children}</TagName>;
}
TextVersion2.displayName = "@Text";

// Works as expected
const anInput1 = <Text as="input" type="text" className="x">input</Text>;
// Error as expected
const aDiv1 = <Text as="div" type="text" className="x">div</Text>;
// Works as expected
const anInput2 = <TextVersion2 as="input" type="text" className="x">input</TextVersion2>;
// ERROR NOT DETECTED <−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− wrong
const aDiv2 = <TextVersion2 as="div" type="text" className="x">div</TextVersion2>;
```